# What is the purpose of update_op return value in tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_auc

Tags: python, tensorflow

I reference this documentation:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/metrics/streaming_auc

For streaming metrics in general, but lets use auc as a simple example, what is the meaning of update_op as a return value?  Must you call this operation after calling streaming_auc() to update the accumulators under the hood for streaming_acu()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need this operation to collect samples and build up your statistics.

Straight from [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.1/api_guides/python/contrib.metrics):

```
labels = ...
predictions = ...
accuracy, update_op_acc = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_accuracy(
    labels, predictions)
error, update_op_error = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_mean_absolute_error(
    labels, predictions)

sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
for batch in range(num_batches):
  sess.run([update_op_acc, update_op_error])

accuracy, mean_absolute_error = sess.run([accuracy, mean_absolute_error])
```